Keep hood with broken latch tied down?
What is a way to keep a hood with a broken (or misaligned) latch down?
I'd like a method such as something with a carabiner so I can easily detach it open the hood.

Note that "best" type posts request opinions and are disallowed on SE. Consider to edit your question to describe a specific solution and address any complications associated with your solution. This would be in line with SE.

The best way is to replace the broken latch. A hood that flips open while driving is likely to have fatal consequences, so I don't recommend any home made contraption.
